# wait for the function to finish before continuing to the next loop in a $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not an expert in JS or jQuery by any means. I'm trying to write code for a chat app that does something like this:

- Get conversation list from an AJAX call
- Populate the left pane of the web page with the conversations returned by the API
- Bind the chat list items to the right side of the pane after the left pane is populated with all the conversations.

Now the issue I'm having is this. After getting the conversation list from the API call, I iterate over the list and bind each item to the pane. .each function goes to the next iteration before the bind function is done executing it's code block. When the function that has the $.each iterator is done executing, I use ".done()' to populate the chat history of the first conversation item. But since the loop is finished before all conversations are binded properly, the chat list is populated and appears before I can see any conversations. Because of this, I can't bind any events to the conversation.

What I'm trying to achieve is to wait for the bind conversation to finish executing and then continue with the iteration.

My code is as below:

```
function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                        if (value.toUser == loggeduser) {
                            var isMe = false;
                            getUser(value.fromUserID, function (user) {
                                if (user.picturename == 'none') {
                                    bindConversationItem(value.chatMessages[0].message, user.username, 'nopic.png', value.conversationID);
                                }
                                else {
                                    bindConversationItem(value.chatMessages[0].message, user.username, user.picturename, value.conversationID);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            getUser(value.toUserID, function (user) {
                                var isMe = true;
                                if (user.picturename == 'none') {
                                    bindConversationItem(value.chatMessages[0].message, user.username, 'nopic.png', value.conversationID);
                                }
                                else {
                                    bindConversationItem(value.chatMessages[0].message, user.username, user.picturename, value.conversationID);
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    });
                }).done(function (data) {
                    populateFirstConversation(data);
                    bindEvents();

                });
```

Here's my bindConversationItem function

```
   function bindConversationItem(message, username, userimage, index) {
            var conv_item = '<li> <a href="#" conversation-index = '+index+' class="clearfix">'
                            + '<img src="http://localhost:1995/contents/member/' + userimage + '" alt="" class="img-circle">'
                            + '<div class="friend-name">'
                                + '<strong>' + username + '</strong>'
                            + '</div>'
                            + '<div class="last-message text-muted">' + message + '</div>'
                            + '<small class="time text-muted">Just now</small>'
                            + '<small class="chat-alert label label-danger">1</small>'
                        + '</a>'
                    + '</li>'


            $("ul.friend-list").append(conv_item);
        }
```

I tried wrapping the code inside a function and using a callback function but I can't seem to get it to work. Any solution here is appreciated.

**Edit**

I have the function "getUser' that is async in the for each loop. Here's what it looks like:

```
            function getUser(userid, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:1995//api/member/' + userid
            }).done(callback)
        }
```

Comment: What function is async in your $.each, getUser()?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba No value is returned from `getUser` call.

Comment: @guest271314 what is it supposed to return? the callback function returns the data from the Ajax response.

Comment: No value is actually returned from the `getUser` function. You could probably use `.queue()`, `$.map()` to return results in sequential order, with next function being called only when current asynchronous process completes. It also appears that `.done()` is chained to `$.each()`? Though `$.each()` does not actually return a value either.

Comment: but what about the call back that is called once the getUser function get's the response from the Ajax call? Because if I'm not returning anything then how am I able to use the value that I get from the Ajax function inside the function that calls getUser method? also does it really matter that I return something in the .each? because the idea is to execute the next sequence of code when the $.each loop finishes. I can use the data value in the chained function as well. If I was using 'then' instead of 'done' then I would have to retur something. Sorry if I sound dumb but please do correct me

Comment: Do not believe it is possible to return a value from `$.each()`. You need to `return` a value from `getUser` or within `.done()`. Alternatively, you could use `$.map()`, `.queue()`, `.promise()`; see Answer below

Comment: ohh no I don't mean return value from $.each() but the function inside which $.each exists. I'm having a look at your code. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123618/discussion-between-ahmed-mujtaba-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.queue()`, `$.map()`, `.promise()` to return results from asynchronous calls in sequential order, perform tasks when all functions in `queueName` have completed

```js
function processQueue (data) {
  return $({}).queue("ajax", $.map(data, function(id) {
    return function(next) {
      return getUser(id, function(val) {
        // do stuff when asynchronous function returns a value
        return $("<div>", {html:"id:" + id + ", value:" + val * Math.PI})
        .appendTo("body").after("<br>"); 
      }, next) // pass `next` function 
    }
  })).dequeue("ajax").promise("ajax")
}

function getUser(value, callback, next) {
  // do asynchronous stuff, e.g., `$.ajax()`
  return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      dfd.resolve(value * 10)
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500))
  })
  // chain `.then()` which calls `callback`, and `.then()`
  // which call next function in `"ajax"` queue
  .then(callback).then(next)
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var queue = processQueue(arr);

// do stuff when queue completes
queue.then(function(data) {
  console.log("complete")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Took some time understanding it but it worked for me. I was just wondering, what if I wanted to return the value from getUser function to the queue object, how do I do that? Like how do I make the promise return this value?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba _"what if I wanted to return the value from getUser function to the queue object"_ You can  create an array at original object wrapped in `jQuery()`, use  `function(next){}` function where `this` is the original jQuery object, push values to the array in object, review the values at `this[0]` at last `.then()`.  https://jsfiddle.net/fqxuwsp7/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution of course is to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but as you have reported you do not know very well about the language, this solution does not impact much your original code:

Instead $.each loop, execute every iteration at a time, then call the next when the callback fires.

```
function (data) {
    function done() {
        populateFirstConversation(data);
        bindEvents();
    }

    function getNextConversation(index) {
        if (index == data.length)
            return done();

        var value = data[index];

        if (value.toUser == ...) {
            getUser(..., function () {
                ...

                getNextConversation(index + 1);
            });
        } else {
           getUser(..., function () {
                ...

                getNextConversation(index + 1);
           });
        }
    }

    getNextConversation(0);
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to the solution you provided but it didn't work exactly as expected. I'll give it a try once more. Shouldn't it be getNextConversation instead of getNextUser? Also is it hard to use promise? what will I need to change?

Comment: Yes, the name should be getNextConversation. What happens wrongly?

Comment: I used a function call back that I passed into the bindConversationItem method and  incremented the index and callback was called. It didn't change the way my code worked before but I didn't try to see what exactly was wrong. Maybe I didn't do it right. I'll give your solution a try